# Foursquare search endpoint

Tags: ios, foursquare

In our app we use foursquare search endpoint to get nearby venues.

Everything was working good until yesterday, but now there is one strange thing, after few refreshes api returns less venues, if i refresh it few times, then normal result is back.

you can check API behaviour by entering this [URL](https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?categoryId=4d4b7104d754a06370d81259%2C4bf58dd8d48988d198941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1af941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1b1941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1a1941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1a0941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1b2941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1a5941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1a7941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1aa941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1a9941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1a3941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1b4941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1ac941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1a2941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1b0941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1a8941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1a6941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1b3941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d141941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1ab941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1ad941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1ae941735%2C4d4b7105d754a06373d81259%2C5267e4d9e4b0ec79466e48c6%2C5267e4d9e4b0ec79466e48c9%2C5267e4d9e4b0ec79466e48c7%2C5267e4d9e4b0ec79466e48d1%2C5267e4d9e4b0ec79466e48c8%2C52741d85e4b0d5d1e3c6a6d9%2C5267e4d8e4b0ec79466e48c5%2C4d4b7105d754a06374d81259%2C4d4b7105d754a06376d81259%2C50327c8591d4c4b30a586d5d%2C4bf58dd8d48988d121941735%2C53e510b7498ebcb1801b55d4%2C4bf58dd8d48988d11f941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d11a941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1d4941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1d6941735%2C52e81612bcbc57f1066b7a27%2C52e81612bcbc57f1066b7a28%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1e2941735%2C52e81612bcbc57f1066b7a22%2C52e81612bcbc57f1066b7a12%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1e5941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d160941735%2C50aaa4314b90af0d42d5de10%2C4bf58dd8d48988d163941735%2C52e81612bcbc57f1066b7a25%2C4bf58dd8d48988d164941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d15e941735%2C52e81612bcbc57f1066b7a26%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1ea941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1ec941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1eb941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1ff931735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d171941735%2C4eb1daf44b900d56c88a4600%2C4bf58dd8d48988d12f941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d196941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d13b941735%2C52e81612bcbc57f1066b7a33%2C4bf58dd8d48988d131941735%2C52e81612bcbc57f1066b7a31%2C4d954b06a243a5684965b473%2C5267e446e4b0ec79466e48c4%2C4bf58dd8d48988d10a951735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d114951735%2C4f04ae1f2fb6e1c99f3db0ba%2C52f2ab2ebcbc57f1066b8b3b%2C4bf58dd8d48988d103951735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1f6941735%2C5454152e498ef71e2b9132c6%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1f7941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1f9941735%2C52f2ab2ebcbc57f1066b8b1c%2C4bf58dd8d48988d18d941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d175941735%2C54541900498ea6ccd0202697%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1f0941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1fd941735%2C52c71aaf3cf9994f4e043d17%2C50be8ee891d4fa8dcc7199a7%2C52f2ab2ebcbc57f1066b8b3c%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1ff941735%2C5032833091d4c4b30a586d60%2C52f2ab2ebcbc57f1066b8b35%2C554a5e17498efabeda6cc559%2C52f2ab2ebcbc57f1066b8b20%2C52f2ab2ebcbc57f1066b8b3d%2C4bf58dd8d48988d10d951735%2C52f2ab2ebcbc57f1066b8b37%2C4bf58dd8d48988d110951735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d123951735%2C52f2ab2ebcbc57f1066b8b41%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1ed941735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1f2941735%2C4d1cf8421a97d635ce361c31%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1de931735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1f3941735%2C4f04b08c2fb6e1c99f3db0bd%2C52f2ab2ebcbc57f1066b8b30%2C4eb1bc533b7b2c5b1d4306cb%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1f7931735%2C4e4c9077bd41f78e849722f9%2C4bf58dd8d48988d12d951735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d12b951735%2C52f2ab2ebcbc57f1066b8b50%2C55077a22498e5e9248869ba2%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1f6931735%2C4bf58dd8d48988d1fa931735%2C4f2a23984b9023bd5841ed2c%2C4e74f6cabd41c4836eac4c31%2C52f2ab2ebcbc57f1066b8b53%2C4bf58dd8d48988d12a951735%2C52f2ab2ebcbc57f1066b8b51%2C4f04b25d2fb6e1c99f3db0c0&client_id=OQ53LWCANNYEWJIIQ4PWOWRRC32C34SVNIMJX4UOBZ1VQMHS&client_secret=LWLKWU1IWT1RY3VZKR1AMXXFMKRLOPVFZAU0Q3USOQA4FGTN&intent=checkin&limit=50&ll=41.722489%2C44.792274&openNow=0&radius=800&v=20150921) and refreshing it few times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@foursquareAPI tweeted as following:

> Some developers might be experiencing issues with venues/search?intent=browse. We're currently investigating!
>   12:37 AM - 22 Sep 2015

I think your problem is also perhaps related to this.

Comment: you are right, there was some problem on foursquare side.